# org scope not found when publishing module

Tags: npm

I have created an org on npm and assigned the *owner* role to my user acc. Now when I want to publish a module with the org scope inside the **package.json** (name : @[MY_ORG_SCOPE]/[MY_MODULE]),
I'm getting the following error :

```
npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 404
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 User not found : @[MY_ORG_SCOPE]/[MY_MODULE]
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@[MY_ORG_SCOPE]/[MY_MODULE]' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
```

Like I said, the user is a part of the org and has the owner role, so it should be possible to publish modules by the current user.

So what could be the problem here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got in touch with the support team. They told me, that there is a bug when converting an existing account to an org, which happened in my case, so they will solve this manually